# PSET 1 Credit CS50

Tags: c, cs50

I'm working on credit PSET from CS50 and I managed to do most of the code but when I reach the conditions to check if the card is Valid it gives me this error when I try to compile it.
use of logical '||' with constant operand, use '|' for a Bitwise operation.
This is the part that breaks in my code.

```
   if (counter > 12 && counter < 17) // check first condition
   {
       if (sum % 10 == 0) // check 2nd condition
       {
           if (number != (4 || 34 || 37 || 51 || 52 || 53 || 54 || 55))
           {
               do
               {
                   testnumber4 /= 10;
               }
               while (testnumber4 != (4 || 34 || 37 || 51 || 52 || 53 || 54 || 55));
               if (testnumber4 == 4)
               {
                   printf("VISA\n");
               }
               else if (testnumber4 == (34 || 37))
               {
                   printf("AMEX\n");
               }
               else if (testnumber4 == (51 || 52 || 53 || 54 || 55))
               {
                   printf("MASTERCARD\n");
               }
               else
               {
                   printf("INVALID\n");
               }
           }
           else
           {
               printf("INVALID\n");
           }
       }
       else
       {
           printf("INVALID\n");
       }
   }
   else
   {
       printf("INVALID\n");
   }
```

Comment: This is not the correct way to test a variable against multiple values. Since the numbers themselves evaluate to true, you are really checking if `testnumber4` and `number` are equal to true which is not what you want.

Comment: Logically compare your operand against *every* value in specific expressions. E.g. you cannot do `if (x != (1 || 2))`. That isn't how the language works. It needs to be `if ((x != 1) && (x != 2))`. You need to be verbose. There are probably a thousand duplicates of this problem on this site, but the mistake is made so frequently by beginners using disparate vernacular to describe their specific side effects (or using completely unrelated verbiage such as your question title), that it is difficult to pin an exact duplicate for example.

Comment: I do indeed have few duplicates for similar misundertandings in my libraray. But none of them is exactly like this one, so I do not dare to hammer-dupe them. I created an answer to be able to add this to the dupe-library. But if anybody can link to a cleanly fitting duplicate I will use that one here and for my lib and would appreciate. @WhozCraig

Comment: How about https://cs50.stackexchange.com/ ...

Comment: Even though OP seems to think that CS50 is part of the problem (not that I want to contradict that in general....), this is something rooted in the contrast between spoken English langauge and programming. I do not see a reason to address this to the CS50 specific community. Using a more speaking title, now that would be a good idea.... @AnttiHaapala--СлаваУкраїні

Comment: @Yunnosch the thing is, if one did search in cs50 community then it is easier to find matching examples.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala--СлаваУкраїні I see, not really cs50 specific, but higher chance to meet people with the same assignments there, which happen to have the same newbie problems. Makes sense, but is no  reason to not ask here (for the brave at heart...).

Comment: You will want to test for 0 in that `while()` loop, or else you've got what is called an "infinite loop" when the credit card "number" does not have a valid prefix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code

```
if (number != (4 || 34 || 37 || 51 || 52 || 53 || 54 || 55))
```

Is an attempt to phrase your logic like you speak it, "number is not 4 or 34...",
or more precisely "number is not anything from the list of 4, 34, ...".

Even with spoken language, this is misunderstandable, but humans usually can tell from context what you mean.
Compiler however are stupid. So you need to be extremely un-misunderstandable. You need to spell it out in extreme detail. You would have to phrase "number is not 4, and number is not 34, and number is not ....".

In C that looks like this

```
if ( (number !=  4)  &&
     (number != 34)  &&
     (number != 37)  &&
     (number != 51)  &&
     (number != 52)  &&
     (number != 53)  &&
     (number != 54)  &&
     (number != 55) 
   )
```

The error you get is explained by how confused the compiler gets trying but failing to understand your logic.
It thinks "take all those numbers and logically or them; hmmm, they are all non-zero; so the result is like 'true or true or true'; hmmm, that does not make sense, maybe you want to binary-or them? That would at least give a somewhat interesting value.".