# Functions are not working in main TicTacToe C++

Tags: c++

When I try to run my code, the process itself seems to work just fine. However, my Validation function won't stop the user from inputting an 'X' or 'O' over another 'X' or 'O'. Along with that, my DetermineWinner function doesn't seem to stop the game in an instance where it otherwise should. I assume I am missing something rather large, but in the case I am not, any advice?

```
    `// This program is designed to create a game of Tic-Tac-Toe under the following rules:
/*
    1. A class IS required.
        - Requires 2D Array of the char or int type as a private variable
        - Other private variables are allowed as needed
        - A public constructor must be used to initialize private variables
        - Two loops are required to access all rows and columns of the 2D array
        - There must be other public functions to do tasks, such as XPlay, OPlay, DetermineAWinner, and others as needed
    2. The main should have a loop to repeat tasks until a win or tie
    3. Verify input. O cannot be placed on a spot where X already is, for example.
*/

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


// As required, a class for the game of TicTacToe exists.
class TicTacToe
{
private:
    char board[3][3];
    char player;

public:

    TicTacToe();
    void retrieveBoard();
    int DetermineWinner(int);
    void PlayerAction(int row, int column);
    double Validation(int row, int column);
};

int main()
{
    int row, column = 0;
    int win = 0;
    TicTacToe ttt;

    cout << "Welcome to Tic Tac Toe! Player 1 will be X's, Player 2 will be O's." << endl << endl;

    ttt.retrieveBoard();
    while (win == 0)
    {
        cout << "Please input the row you wish to play on." << endl;
        cin >> row;
        cout << "Please input the column you wish to play on." << endl;
        cin >> column;
        cout << endl << endl;

        ttt.Validation(row, column);
        ttt.PlayerAction(row, column);
        ttt.retrieveBoard();
        ttt.DetermineWinner(win);
    }
    
    // Once the while loop is broken, determine if a win or tie was made.
    if (win == 1)
    {
        cout << "Player 1 is the winner!\n";
    }
    else if (win == 2)
    {
        cout << "Player 2 is the winner!\n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "A tie was made.";
    }
    
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

    

// Constructor for the class. Two loops are used to create the board's basis.
TicTacToe::TicTacToe()
{
    for (int r = 0; r < 3; r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < 3; c++)
        {
            board[r][c] = '*';
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    player = 'X';
}

// When called, will display the board.
void TicTacToe::retrieveBoard()
{
    for (int r = 0; r < 3; r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < 3; c++)
        {
            cout << board[r][c] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

// Used to play each action. The end of each turn will also switch players.
void TicTacToe::PlayerAction(int row, int column)
{
    if (player == 'X')
    {
        board[row][column] = 'X';
        player = 'O';
    }

    else
    {
        board[row][column] = 'O';
        player = 'X';
    }
}

// When called, will check the player's action to make sure the move is valid. If not, the player must input a new action. Preferably a valid one.
double TicTacToe::Validation(int row, int column)
{
    while (board[row][column] == ('X' | 'O'))
    {
        cout << "Please play in a place that has not been played yet.\n";
        cin >> row, column;
    }
    return row, column;
}

// Function used to determine the winner when called. Honestly I banged my head against a wall trying to figure out how to create this.
int TicTacToe::DetermineWinner(int winner)
{
    // Used to check each row for a horizontal victory.
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        if (board[i][0] == board[i][1] && board[i][1] == board[i][2])
        {
            if (board[i][0] == 'X')
                winner = 1;
            else
                winner = 2;
            return winner;
        }
    }
    // Used to check each column for a vertical victory.
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        if (board[0][i] == board[1][i] && board[1][i] == board[2][i])
        {
            if (board[0][i] == 'X')
                winner = 1;
            else
                winner = 2;
            return winner;
        }
    }
    // Two more checks are made to determine if a diagnal victory exists.
    if (board[0][0] == board[1][1] && board[1][1] == board[2][2])
    {
        if (board[0][0] == 'X')
            winner = 1;
        else
            winner = 2;
        return winner;
    }

    if (board[0][2] == board[1][1] && board[1][1] == board[2][0])
    {
        if (board[0][2] == 'X')
            winner = 1;
        else
            winner = 2;
        return winner;
    }
  
    // A check needs to be made to make sure available spaces still exist.
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            if (board[i][j] == '*')
            {
                winner = 0;
                return winner;
            }
        }
    }
    winner = -1;
    return winner;
}`
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code with a debugger to see why it does not stop at moments you expect it to? You might want to look read up on reference parameters or why not ignore return values.

Comment: `('X' | 'O')` is `'_'`. "A is X or Y" translated into logic is "A is X or A is Y", not "A is the bitwise-or of X and Y".

Comment: I am with molbnilo concerning `while (board[row][column] == ('X' | 'O'))` and I consider this a duplicate (even though in a different language): https://stackoverflow.com/a/73764742/7733418 Let me know if it is similar enough for you to accept it as an answer.

Comment: `cin >> row, column` should be `cin >> row >> column`

Answer (score 2):

A lot of things are not in the correct place here.

First of all your `Validation` function implementation:

1. `double TicTacToe::Validation(int row, int column)`
   This is promising a double as a return value, but the function will return an int:
   `return row, column;` ([read more about comma operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54142/how-does-the-comma-operator-work-and-what-precedence-does-it-have))
2. Then the idea itself, from this function you probably want to return (or notify somehow) the new values to the caller. What you probably want is a function with a firm like:
   `void TicTacToe::Validation(int &row, int &column)` This way you will accept references and it will directly update the values passed by the caller.
3. And last but not least, the check to verify if a cell is already used: `while (board[row][column] == ('X' | 'O'))` it's not what you think. The correct way to write it is: `while (board[row][column] == 'X' || board[row][column] =='O')`
4. As Alan said in the comments there is also this:

> `cin >> row, column;` should be `cin >> row >> column;`
> Always for the comma operator mentioned before.

The same problem at the point number 2 is present also for the function that checks if someone won:
`int DetermineWinner(int);`
Here you are accepting a parameter by value, then at the end returning it, but you never use the return value from that function.
You have two options here:

1. Same solution as before, accept a reference `void DetermineWinner(int& winner);` and you don't need to do anything else.
2. Probably better solution is to have the function as you have (without parameter maybe) and use the return value where you call it: `win = ttt.DetermineWinner();`

I think starting from here you should be able to fix all of your problems.

I also agree with the comment that suggest to look into that with a debugger, you will be able to spot all of these issues just stepping through code.